# I'm having trouble clearing my MySQL table through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a program which sends delayed Emails using **MySQL, PHP, and a Cron Job through Godaddy.** Ultimately, this will be an automated process, but for the time being I am doing everything manually. After emails are sent, I would like them to be wiped from my database table named mailbox. I run into an issue when I try to write the bit of code that wipes my table. I am trying to use `"TRUNCATE TABLE mailbox"` at the moment, but have also tried `"DELETE FROM mailbox"` with no luck. I also removed the back ticks and received undesirable results. Currently the file looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once( ".htpasswd2" );

$mailQuery = "select * from mailbox";
$mailResults = mysql_query( $mailQuery );

for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $mailResults ); $i++ ) { 

$mailArray = mysql_fetch_array( $mailResults );

$msg = "On " . date('M jS, Y') . " at " . date('g:i:sa') .
" " . $mailArray[ 'from' ] . " wrote <p>" . $mailArray[ 'message' ];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "To: " . $mailArray[ 'to' ] . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $mailArray[ 'from' ] . "<" . $mailArray[ 'reply' ] . ">" . "\r\n";

mail( $mailArray['to'], $mailArray['subject'], $msg, $headers );

 }

 $clearTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE mailbox";

mysql_query( $clearTable );


?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `or die(mysql_error());`, & check the error.

Comment: check the response from mysql_query and check the value of mysql_error.  That should tell you what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion bluesmoon. This file is strictly PHP and SQL, so at first I didn't consider mysql_error as an option (no where to output the error). However, now that I think about it I am already opening this in a browser to run the program, so it isn't too far out of my way to throw in my 8 HTML tags and create a spot for the error message. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: mysql_error spat out this message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`mailbox`' at line 1  

What do you make of it?

Answer (score 0):

this may work

```
$clearTable = " TRUNCATE TABLE `mailbox` ";
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried adding the backticks in the past with no success. I am curious, why would adding spaces at the beginning and end of the string help? My gut says that would generate a syntax error.